# What is the specificity of var?

Tags: c#, var

So, as far as a question to a real problem goes, this probably isn't a very good question, but it's bugging me and I can't find an answer, so I consider that to be a problem.

What is the specificity of `var`? The [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) on it states the following:

> An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself

Bur it doesn't seem to say anywhere what type it is strongly typed for. For example, if I have the following:

```
var x = new Tree();
```

But I then don't call any methods of `Tree`, is `x` still strongly typed to `tree`? Or could I have something like the following?

```
var x = new Tree();
x = new Object();
```

I'm guessing this isn't allowed, but I don't have access to a compiler right now, and I'm really wondering if there are any caveats that allow unexpected behaviour like the above.

Comment: My bad, I've now removed the second initialization of `x` so it's what I *meant* to write...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's strongly typed to the type of the expression on the right side:

> The var keyword instructs the compiler to infer the type of the variable from the expression on the right side of the initialization statement.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx).

Comment: This doesn't entirely answer the question. I am aware that it infers the type according to the right-hand side, but the specificity of the inferred type is what I was wondering about. If it's only inferring it from the right-hand side, though, I suppose it has to be as specific as possible.

Comment: Why doesn't this answer the question? The type is inferred to be the type of the expression on the right side of the assignment. That means that it will match it exactly.

Comment: Oh, yup. My bad, I was not thinking in terms of the type of the *expression*, but rather of the type of the object *produced* by the expression.

Comment: Well, they're the same thing. The expression will evaluate to a value or object of a particular type. That type, specifically, will be used as the type of the variable being declared with `var` when it is created in memory and assigned the result of the expression. Not a base class, not a further derived class, not a co- or-contravariant generic type, *that* type.

Answer (score 6):

It's tied to the type on the right-side of the equals-sign, so in this case, it is equivalent to:

```
Tree x = new Tree();
```

Regardless of whatever interface or base classes are tied to `Tree`. If you need `x` to be of a lower type, you have to declare it specifically, like:

```
Plant x = new Tree();
// or
IHasLeaves x = new Tree();
```

Comment: Alternatively, `var x = (Plant) new Tree();` - I will leave that can of worms untouched otherwise ..

Comment: @pst Nice - definitely would work, but if I see that in a code review, I'm shooting the developer with a Nerf dart :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in your example `x` is strongly typed to `Tree` `just as if you had declared the type yourself`.

Your second example would not compile because you are redefining `x`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is *exactly* the same, had you typed `Tree x = new Tree();`. Obviously the only unambiguous inference the compiler can do is the exact type of the right hand side expression, so it won't suddenly become `ITree x`

So this doesn't work:

```
Tree x = new Tree();
x = new Object(); //cannot convert implicitly
```

If you are curious, the `dynamic` is closer to the behavior you expect.

```
dynamic x = new Tree();
x = new Object();
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is nowhere in the documentation that says that `var` must be unambiguous. In my example it could be statically inferred that the `var` doesn't need to be a `Tree`.

Comment: @Jeff No I meant, say for example, Tree implements 2 interfaces. How would it choose between them just from seeing this information `var x = new Tree()`?

Comment: It wouldn't. But if that was literally the only reference to `x` in the program then it could safely be of type `Object` instead.

Comment: @Jeff How could it see from `var x = new Tree()`, that `x` could be safely of type `Object`?

Comment: It can't if it only checks that particular expression. If it checks the whole program, however, it is possible, since if there is no use of anything at a more specific level than `Object` then there is no need for it to be anything more specific.

Comment: @Jeff but the documentation specifically says that it only checks the immediate expression on right side :P You could be correct that if it parsed the whole program and analyzed it before decision.. but it doesn't

Comment: Well sure, I know that now. +1 for mentioning the dynamic keyword =) I learned something new.

Comment: @Jeff - suppose the compiler analyses everywhere the variable is used and so chooses the type accordingly. If it did that, how would we be able to detect that it was doing it?

Comment: @DanielEarwicker You probably wouldn't, until you tried to compile something that doesn't make sense. Doesn't mean it can't be be done.

Comment: But if you say something that doesn't make sense, you get a compile error. That's true with the compiler right now, and should still be true if they implement your idea. It doesn't allow us to detect whether they have implemented your idea. The point being: they could have already implemented it! We can't tell whether they have or not.

Comment: NB. Unless we look at the IL after compiling, where every variable has a specific type!

Answer (score 1):

In the example:

```
var x = new Tree();
```

is the same as

```
Tree x = new Tree();
```

I've found it is always better to use "var" since it facilitates code re-factoring.

Also, adding,

```
var x = new Object();
```

in the same scope would break compilation due to the fact that you cannot declare a variable twice.

Comment: (On some occasions though, `var` can be "too specific", especially when an interface is more applicable.)

Comment: That is a great observation pst.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is neither a type nor does it make the variable something special. It tells the compiler to infer the type of the variable AT COMPILE TIME by analyzing the initialization expression on the right hand side of the assignment operator.

These two expressions are equivalent:

```
Tree t = new Tree();
```

and

```
var t = new Tree();
```

---

Personally I prefer to use `var` when the type name is mentioned explicitly on the right hand side or when the exact type is complicated and not really relevant as for results returned from LINQ queries. These LINQ results are often just intermediate results that are processed further:

```
var x = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
```

is easier to read than the following statement and yet very clear:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> x = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
```

```
var query = someSource
    .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("A"))
    .GroupBy(x => x.State)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Date);
```

Here `query` is of type `IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<string, SomeType>>`. Who cares?

---

When the type name does not appear on the right hand side and is simple, then I prefer to write it explicitly as it doesn't simplify anything to use `var`:

```
int y = 7;
string s = "hello";
```

And of cause, if you create anonymous types, you must use `var` because you have no type name:

```
var z = new { Name = "Coordinate", X = 5.343, Y = 76.04 };
```

---

The `var` keyword was introduced together with LINQ in order to simplify their use and to allow to create types on the fly in order to simulate the way you would work with SQL:

```
SELECT Name, Date FROM Person
```

```cs
var result = DB.Persons.Select(p => new { p.Name, p.Date });
```